# unable to upload image greater than 4 gb on AWS ECR, ERROR reincarnated worker Process-1:4 after death

Tags: kubernetes, worker, django-q

Sending .tar file from frontend to backend and in backend receives binary of tar file
and once we get that file we are starting Django q and using it upload it to AWS ECR layer by layer
Here is the Q-cluster configuration :

```
Q_CLUSTER = {
  "name": "abc",
  "workers": 8,
  "recycle": 500,
  'attempt_count': 1,
  'ack_failures': True,
  "compress": True,
  "save_limit": 250,
  "queue_limit": 500,
  "cpu_affinity": 1,
  "label": "Django Q",
  "redis": {
      "host": REDIS_HOST,
      "port": REDIS_PORT,
      "db": 0,
  },
}
```

So the Error getting while uploading :

```
[INFO] Starting pushing layer 66ffede0daa0486a61c11446bcb954ad89df6c2cb567ecd6ab97c12228ef6e8f/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started

[INFO] Starting pushing layer 4562d7acfd41cfad11b031cdd9bcd217dcd3cd36fd0cc5aabfc8df18e3a6972b/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
[INFO] Starting pushing layer bacd26a46504a4282343e37dac8ac4c24ee649fe85c605547d57960822e076fe/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
Pushing... 100.0%  

[INFO] Starting pushing layer 29165659eb61efe28b84e580bdca126a60a356655dd62a6bed38d61a496fa6aa/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
[INFO] Starting pushing layer 50e432f951ede2c9c9c299f8a68e106282af2f59fdf1120ec9cc084a1005da22/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
Pushing... 100.0%  
[INFO] Starting pushing layer dc984c3c30a1a444dfdfcdff0686ef712412716920ad8fe619787f7735ab156e/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
[INFO] Starting pushing layer fe6d7993f09d1b294ae3980f370e0b9b434941bfa99c85a3c63428c0f6a1a2e7/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
[INFO] Starting pushing layer b561779bae7406e1a97dae43f3c0b45e5dd8a52d359aae533e670775cb0464df/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
[INFO] Starting pushing layer 170d1e7a28c707797b61f0f54c14f5ad2cff239855a823e3c2442ef09adf0ab5/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
[INFO] Starting pushing layer f521d5101bf2325bb2e210dbd9c86c1608ab083c4f2d819cf8bc205810492474/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
[INFO] Starting pushing layer 2908c3588dbe82e5eaac1f06a0b3a5d60b7d689d489c28d3c95b310c23d18bd2/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
[INFO] Starting pushing layer 27bcf483885811cb8ee15fd784cf8115910a78505fd98f54d013b14cf7b0b923/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
[INFO] Starting pushing layer 4d19ecbd1fbd26168147a173d7085150b661957dd7244fe154f1f48efd53302f/layer.tar
[INFO] Upload started
Pushing... 100.0%  
Pushing... 100.0%  
Pushing... 100.0%  


Pushing... 100.0%  
Pushing... 100.0%  
Pushing... 100.0%  
Pushing... 100.0%  
10:43:00 [Q] ERROR reincarnated worker Process-1:4 after death
10:43:00 [Q] INFO Process-1:11 ready for work at 50
```

I tried attempt_count = 1 and ack_failures = True but still getting error in worker

Comment: My practical experience is that individual layers above about 1 GiB or so will hit random trouble like this, both pushing and pulling.  What is in the image's Dockerfile?  Can you split the problematic large layer?

Comment: yes it's tar file of docker file and basically we extract the tar file in backend and will push layer by layer.